# OAuth 2.0 (Google API) authentication from a WPF desktop application

Tags: wpf, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-latitude

I would like to use OAuth 2.0 from within a WPF application I am developing but I am stuck. It appears that the OAuth 2.0 works by forwarding you to a website and getting you confirm details.

Of course this is a WPF app, and I wonder if there are any work-arounds.

Specifically I am trying to authenticate with OAuth 2.0 for use with the google latitude API located here

```
https://developers.google.com/latitude/v1/using#auth
```

Are there examples of how to authenticate against OAuth 2.0 from a WPF desktop app?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454930/google-api-how-can-i-use-refreshtokens-to-avoid-requesting-access-every-time-m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a sample WPF application that uses the google-api-dotnet-client library in the project repository:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client

This sample app uses the Tasks API, but it should be pretty easy to adapt it to use the Latitude API instead.