# Google API Autentication - redirect_uri_mismatch error

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to authenticate my web app with [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/). In the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) under Credentials for my `Cliend Id for Web Application`.

I add the following redirect uri: `http://localhost:50883/oauth/add_oauth_token`

When I run my application I get the following Error:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Application: SID3

You can email the developer of this application at: carlosmoralesdiego@gmail.com

The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:55404/authorize/ did not match a registered   redirect URI.

Learn more

Request Details
from_login=1
response_type=code
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://localhost:55404/authorize/
as=-45fed094242eac62
pli=1
client_id=389029010035-knoo3a2445r77pirc06h8fhgdc5q0dsv.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
hl=es
```

So for any reason google changes my redirect uri to the port 55404, why?. Thanks so much and regards

This is the code:

```
protected void LoginToGooglePlus(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        PlusService service = null;
        UserCredential credential = null;

            string[] scopes = new string[] {PlusService.Scope.PlusLogin, PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail,
 PlusService.Scope.UserinfoProfile};
            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
           try
        {
            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
            UserCredential credentials;
            using (var stream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {

                credentials= GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, scopes, Environment.UserName, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("WebApplication1")).Result;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //If the user hits cancel you wont get access.
            if (ex.InnerException.Message.IndexOf("access_denied") != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User declined access");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unknown Authentication Error:" + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
        }

        // Now we create a Google service. All of our requests will be run though this.
        service = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "SID3",
        });




}
```

The json file which I use it's this one:

```
{"web":{"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","client_secret":"jpkVDaaMjlLCHGh67DJ9Zv19","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","client_email":"389029010035-knoo3a2445r77pirc06h8fhgdc5q0dsv@developer.gserviceaccount.com","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:50880/Paneles.aspx"],"client_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/389029010035-knoo3a2445r77pirc06h8fhgdc5q0dsv@developer.gserviceaccount.com","client_id":"389029010035-knoo3a2445r77pirc06h8fhgdc5q0dsv.apps.googleusercontent.com","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"}}
```

Comment: I don't think Google is changing your port I think your asp debug session is changing your port. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109(v=vs.100).aspx   Redirect uri must be the same as the one you are calling to.

Comment: Hello Linda, I put it on a static port and nothing, it doesn't work, so I don't know what to do. Thanks

Comment: you will need to post your code I think.  and try adding the full file to the redirect uri http://localhost:50883/oauth/add_oauth_token/test.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the same problem simply by changing DataStore to null.

```
credentials= GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    scopes,
    Environment.UserName,
    CancellationToken.None,
    null // <-- here
    ).Result;
```

I don't know why but it stops the random port shenanigans.
I should also add, that in my case, it just solved one problem since I needed to publish my app online, where this solution was just wrong. If anyone needs the online version (asp.net 4.5 MVC 5) you can use the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843907/5478049).

Answer (score -2):

API redirect URL and your application Redirect URL Should be same....
For example (if your application URL Like this localhost:55404/authorize/ and need to add same URL in API Redirect URL localhost:55404/authorize/ )

Comment: I have the same problem using Google Calendar API v3 and that's not a solution, since IIS always change the port.