# Gmail API access using c#

Tags: gmail-api

I tried to use google APIs but returned error url

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://127.0.0.1:50528/authorize/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit:

Comment: Can you try checking out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143907/google-api-autentication-redirect-uri-mismatch-error) if it is helpful?

Comment: this issue on gmail api not google api