# new FileDataStore in GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker results in a new port each time

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth, google-oauth-.net-client

So I followed a few examples from http://www.daimto.com/, namely http://www.daimto.com/webmaster-tools-api-with-c/. After a long night I was able to get it to work. the way I did that is by simply removing

```
new FileDataStore("Daimto.GoogleWebMasters.Auth.Store")
```

changing the code to:

```
  UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker(new ClientSecrets 
{ ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }                                                                                            
, scopes                                                                                     
, userName                                                                                 
, CancellationToken.None                                                                      
, null).Result; // <-- notice null here
```

So is the datastore really necessary? when I add it, my IIS is generating a new port number each refresh, making it impossible to authorize url redirects in google.
btw, I tried the physical full path of the directory, but it results the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this solution was just the wrong way, perhaps just obsolete. Finally, I rewrote everything base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31843907/5478049). Now it works find both on local and published, and with FileDataStore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include file datastore or any datastore for that matter by default the client library will use file datastore and create the file in %appData%

So technically speaking you don't need to use it.

**What does FileDataStore do exactly?**

Lets look at FileDataStore.   When the following code authenticates. A folder called Drive.Auth.Store will be created in the %AppData% directory on the machine executing the code.

So we will have a new directory called  %AppDatat%\Drive.Auth.Store .  When I check my machine I find it here C:\Users\lindaHP\AppData\Roaming\Drive.Auth.Store

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(clientSecretsJsonFilePath
                                   ,FileMode.Open
                                   ,FileAccess.Read))
      {   
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
      new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,  DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
      "LookIAmAUniqueUser",
       CancellationToken.None,
      new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")                               
      ).Result;
      }
```

Assuming the user clicks accept on the authentication request screen, a new file will be created in that directory with the following structure:

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser.TokenResponse-LookIAmAUniqueUser

Each user will have their own file you change a user by changing the “LookIAmAUniqueUser” value.

The file contains all the information you need to gain access to this users account.

**alternate tutorial**

I have an other tutorial for you.  [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

**Note from me**

I have no idea how not using filedatastore would change the port appearing or not.   I need to test this it could be a bug in the client library. or a feature I guess depending upon how you look at it.

Comment: In GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/LocalServerCodeReceiver.cs, the port is assigned randomly in GetRandomUnusedPort()

Comment: Thank you DalmTo, I read what you suggested, and tried a custom DataStore. This did not change the random port problem. Furthermore, I discovered that when I publish the solution, it throws an error. All these issues were solved by avoid using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker and going with the solution I linked in the answer I've added.