# What is the minimum user roles/permission for using Google Email Audit API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-audit-api

I am getting start with Google Apps Admin SDK > Email Audit API,
I can successfully call the API

`GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/monitor/{domain name}/{source user name}`

using OAuth token authorized by a super admin account, but I cannot use the super-admin to build my service due to permission issue.

We have another account specific for using this API, we want to setup a custom role for this account to minimize to permission grant to this account, but we fail to find the right permission for Email Audit API.

So my question is: What is the minimal roles/permission in google admin panel for the user be able to use **ALL** Email Audit API feature?

Answer (score 0):

You may check on this [support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1219251?hl=en) the privileges that can be associated with administrator roles in the Google Admin console. You can also refer with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946873/email-audit-api-403-forbidden/32119171) which recommends to use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation). *"After emailing Google support, I learned I could just use OAuth2 for the super user account that created the application on the developer's console."* Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, however we are going to use Gmail API with domain wide delegation as that better fit my usage. BTW, I have already checked the support page you mentioned and that didn't help us in this case.