# How to call GData services with an OAuth access token?

Tags: c#, .net, gdata

I have an OAuth access token that I got from:

```
var state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/" })
{
    Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl)
};

// Redirect to:
var authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state)
...

var authState = arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
```

After that, how do I pass the `authState.AccessToken` to the services from the GData API?

All the [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454930/google-api-how-can-i-use-refreshtokens-to-avoid-requesting-access-every-time-m) I find pass an `OAuth2Authenticator<>` to the constructor of the service, such as:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(...);
var service = new PlusService(auth);
```

I am trying to use the `ContactsService` but the latest version (2.2.0.0) does not seem to have this constructor - the only constructor takes an application name.

I have tried setting the access token with `ContactsService.SetAuthenticationToken()` but the request header is incorrectly set, it will look like this:

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=<access token>
```

Instead of:

```
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
```

There does not seem to be any method to manipulate the headers either.

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same problem. Instead of using SetAuthenticationToken(), you should assign the RequestFactory with an OAuth2RequestFactory as suggested by the examples provided on the GData API page.

Now this seems somewhat counter-intuitive if you already are managing OAuth tokens outside of the GData API. It turns out that you do not need to actually provide the clientId, clientSecret, etc to the request factory. The only field that matters is the OAuth access token, if that is a valid access token.

At least for us, we found that with this approach, the GData API correctly specifies the Authorization Http header, and the API calls are successful.