# How to make CalendarService object using access_token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use google calendar v3 api using .net client. I am follwing a hybrid approach. I have authorized my application using oauth2 using only http post request and I get the access_token. But as .net client of calendar v3 api, I need to make a calendarservice reference. I need to find any way to get that service reference using my token. Have a look at this code snippet:

```
Event event = new Event()
{
  Summary = "Appointment",     
};

Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(event, "primary").Fetch();
// here "service" is authenticate calendarservice instance.

Console.WriteLine(recurringEvent.Id);
```

and this is the code to get authenticated calendarservice instance:

```
 UserCredential credential;
 using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {
      credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar },
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("something"));
 }

  // Create the service instance.
  var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
  {
          HttpClientInitializer = credential,
          ApplicationName = "Books API Sample",
  });
```

This code shows the authorization code flow according to Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 and then make service reference using that credential. Actually this is a helper utility to manage authorization code flow. To be clear, I am not using this procedure.(this helper utility). I am trying to do everything in core level that means I have made authorization code flow manually by simple HTTP web request. And I have done authorization perfectly. Now I have that users access_token.

Now my question is that how can I create this service instance manually only using that access_token. If anything bother you, feel free to ask anything.

N.B - I know how to create CalendarService instance:

```
 var service = new CalendarService();
```

but how can I create this type instance with connected to authenticated token which I have.

Comment: Are you only trying to access your calender? or do you to allow users to access there calenders via your app?

Comment: @DaImTo I will need to access their calendar so that I can post event into their calendar. User will authenticate that permission. I have did that part and with permission(calendar r/w scope) I have that access token.

Comment: looking for something similar in PHP if anyone can guide

Answer (score 13):

The question was asked about a year ago but anyway here is the code I use to initialize CalendarService having accessToken only.

At first, I implemented a "clone" of UserCredential class based on its source code but removing all unnecessary staff related to Google APIs OAuth2 methods

```
internal class CustomUserCredential : IHttpExecuteInterceptor, IConfigurableHttpClientInitializer
{
    private string _accessToken;

    public CustomUserCredential(string accessToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public void Initialize(ConfigurableHttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.MessageHandler.ExecuteInterceptors.Add(this);
    }

    public async Task InterceptAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
    }
}
```

After that, creating an instance of CalendarService looks pretty simple:

```
private CalendarService GetCalendarService(string accessToken)
    {
        return new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = new CustomUserCredential(accessToken),
                ApplicationName = "AppName"
            });
    }
```

Comment: This was enormously helpful. Is there a good reason for a simple class like this not being a part of the .NET API?  This problem mostly took me a long time to figure out because I was sure that I simply wasn't finding the correct classes in the API.  It was surprising to find out that they don't exist for doing basic oauth2 authentication to the API.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you @AlexeyGureski.

Comment: Alexey, you can add that answer to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039044/using-the-google-api-net-client-with-an-existing-access-token and I will mark it as answer! Thanks for your help.

Comment: This worked for AnalyticsReportingService as well to enable report extracts from Google Analytics UA

Answer (score 0):

The example you uses `FileDataStore`.

How FileDataStore works - The first time you run the code it will ask the user if they want to let you access there calender.  The information is then stored in your %appData%  directory. If you want to load a refresh token that you have for example stored in the database you cant.

Stored Refreshtoken - In order to use a refreshToken that you for example have stored in the database you need to create your own implimitation of `IdataStore`.   Once you have done that you will be able to send the refresh token that you saved previously.

This tutorial should help you understand http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/

You dont need to deal with getting new access token the Service will use the RefreshTokens to get a new access token for you.

If this doesnt help post a comment and i will see if i can expend it a little more.

Comment: @DalmTo I didn't use FileDataStore. I have given that code to know how to do that manually. I have gained access_token manually by using http request to api. Now I need to make that service reference using that access_token. Did you get my point?

Comment: your code has  new FileDataStore("something"));  And you state that your using  calendar v3 api.  Createing all of the oauth2 calls yourself requires a little more work.  check this link let me know if you need any help: http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/

Comment: @DalmTo Please see my edit in the question. I have added some more information to clear my problem. I think you will get that. I am not using that helper utilty class provided by google calendar. I am doing it manually. And I have completed authorization process successfully. Just need to make that Service reference using that access_token to use .net client.

Answer (score 0):

I like @alexey's response the best but as an alternative you can initialize with the simple constructor and then pass the access token in on each request, like this:

```
// Create service
var service = new CalendarService();

// Request
var request = service.Events.Get("x", "y");
request.OauthToken = accessToken;
var response = request.Execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Your solution should look very similar to this one: 
[.NET Google api 1.7 beta authenticating with refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007866/net-google-api-1-7-beta-authenticating-with-refresh-token)

Remember to set the ExpiresInSeconds and Issued properties, so the library won't think that the access_token has expired (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Responses/TokenResponse.cs#66)

Comment: I have tried code from that reference but somehow it's not working.