# Google.Apis client for C#sharp auth using refresh token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using new beta Google APIs Client Library for .NET to load tasks lists of more than one user. It's classified as "installed aplication" (according to google dev. console) with more than one authorized user accounts. It's really simple to authenticate one user (using google.apis) but I cannot figure out, how to do the same with refresh tokens, and how to use this tokens to get service object.

Sample code:

```
var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(GoogleTools.GenerateStreamFromString(GoogleTools.Cred)).Secrets,
new[] { TasksService.Scope.Tasks },
"user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Tasks.Auth.Store")).Result;         


// Create the service.
service = new TasksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
     HttpClientInitializer = credential,
     ApplicationName = "Tasks API Sample",
});
```

I want to construct object `credential` using refresh token, but I'm really lost and cannot find any appropriate documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET Google api 1.7 beta authenticating with refresh token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007866/net-google-api-1-7-beta-authenticating-with-refresh-token)

Answer (score 7):

You can check if the current Token is expired and Refresh using the code below:

```
if (credential.Token.IsExpired(Google.Apis.Util.SystemClock.Default))
{
  var refreshResult = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

After that the credential has the `credential.Token.AccessToken` and `credential.Token.RefreshToken` refreshed

Comment: Will this update the FileDataStore object? Your suggestion seems so simple compared to the other answer.

Comment: `GoogleCredential.FromAccessToken` there's no `RefreshTokenAsync`

Answer (score 1):

I already answer to that one in the following thread:
[.NET Google api 1.7 beta authenticating with refresh token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007866/net-google-api-1-7-beta-authenticating-with-refresh-token)

Hope it will be helpful for you as well.