# youtube api token upload video

Tags: c#, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, token

I am retriving a token through an website, then I save the token, and refresh token in a database. Then I am writing .net program that uploads video's located on our server to youtube. My problem is to get the program I am making, use the stored token. I am using one of google's examples to upload the video. But the program should use the already saved token, instead os asking for new credentials.

The current code is this.

```
UserCredential credential;

        //credential.UserCredential(,"",)

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );

        }
        Console.WriteLine("HER");

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
```

So instead I would like to use an already saved token.

Any help, or a pointer in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Comment: How old are the tokens that you're storing? A normal access token expires after an hour or so, and so you can't use it repeatedly without getting a new one. When you first store the access token and the refresh token, also store the expiry time of the access token. Then, before ever making a call, check your time to see if it's expired. If it is, use the refresh token to get a new access token and set it, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I am storing the refreshtoken also, so I can refresh it. 

But my problem is how to use the stored(valid) token to upload a video. The above code asks for a new credentials. So I would like to change the above code, to use the stored access token.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` instead of `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` in order to use the refresh token. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21010041/1501074).