# upload video to youtube in .net

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need to upload a video in .NET
I use your client library. And when I receive code at my callback url, I need to change this code for token.
How can I do this? I didn't find any information about this.
And then, where should I put this token, uploading a video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just like other [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/java) using Youtube API, you must also follow the steps on how to obtain your `client_secret.json` that contains your `token_uri`:

> - Use this wizard to create or select a project in the Google Developers Console and automatically turn on the API. Click **Continue**,
>     then **Go to credentials**.
> - On the **Add credentials to your project** page, click the **Cancel** button.
> - At the top of the page, select the **OAuth consent screen** tab. Select an **Email address**, enter a **Product name** if not already set, and click
>     the **Save** button.
> - Select the **Credentials** tab, click the **Create credentials** button and select **OAuth client ID**.
> - Select the application type **Other**, enter the name "YouTube Data API Quickstart", and click the **Create** button.
> - Click **OK** to dismiss the resulting dialog.
> - Click the **download icon** (Donwload JSON) button to the right of the client ID.
> - Move the downloaded file to your working directory and rename it `client_secret.json`.

client_secret.json

```
{"installed":{"client_id":"837380381682-kthu0nva0f5tqli35o6hk4jiv0p9mh3s.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"sureness-1534400441179","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"n-5X4ssSnqw9JXFOrLAl1J1y","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
```

This is a code snippet from [.Net Code Sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet)  where `client_secrets.json` was implemented:

> ```
>  UserCredential credential;
>   using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
>   {
>     credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
>         GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
>         // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
>         // authenticated user's account.
>         new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
>         "user",
>         CancellationToken.None,
>         new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
>     );
>   }
> ```

Comment: after that there's the request at my callback. I receive code. What should I do then with that? I need to exchange this code for token. How can I do that? and then how can I use it in following requests?

Comment: If you're referring to refreshed tokens, you can check this google documentation -> https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#exchange-authorization-code regarding Exchange authorization code for refresh and access tokens.

Comment: and where should I put this token in .NET library, when I want to upload video?

Comment: Have you checked this related SO post? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454930/google-api-how-can-i-use-refreshtokens-to-avoid-requesting-access-every-time-m

Comment: Well, the problem is:
When I call authorizeAsync. Redirect via browser occurs. I let give all the required permissions for this app. Then it makes request to callback (myapp/authorize). I receive code and with that code I can receive token. Then I should use this token in all following request. And I have no idea, how to create youTubeService object with this token instead credentials object (according to your documentation)

Comment: when the method AuthorizeAsync is called, it just returns redirect, and the object credential is not filled with the data.